# How to stop build agent from waiting in the pipeline process in Azure devops

Tags: python, azure-devops, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, webhooks, aws-step-functions

I have been able to put together a pipeline that trigger a step function in AWS through a python script which estimated to run for 7 hours and the next job in the pipeline depends on the successful completion of the step function. The next job is also a python script that generate tables in snowflakes for 30 hours. This is working as expected, but there is need for improvement. The build agent in the Azure devops pipeline is waiting for 30 hours which is not good. I am looking at efficient way to trigger the python script that call the snowflakes and exit the pipeline to stop the build agent from waiting.

What are the options available?

1. Is it possible to use lambda to call this snowflakes and exit the pipeline and how would the pipeline get notification if anything goes wrong ?
2. There is suggestion to use webbook and have not used webhook before, is there any pointer to use this?

Comment: What do your python scripts do during the waiting time? Are they just polling snowflake waiting for the job to finish or do they actually perform operations?

Comment: The python script is working and calling sql script also creating views and tables and , it just sends sql queries to execution queue in different warehouses

Comment: Does it get the result of sql queries' executions? Like if they failed or not

Comment: It prints the sql error but not stopping the pipeline

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. Is it possible to use lambda to call this snowflakes and exit the pipeline and how would the pipeline get notification if anything goes wrong ?

Lambda Functions timeout after 15 minutes. So, just putting your script into Lambda Function won't work.

> 2. There is suggestion to use webbook and have not used webhook before, is there any pointer to use this?

Webhook is just a way of invoking another service via HTTP call. When you call Lambda Function or Step Function via API Gateway, you can consider it as a webhook. There might be also a webhook on Snowflake side to perform some actions. This doesn't solve the script execution part though.

I suggest to use Step Function with Lambda Functions in the following way:

1. Extract SQL queries from your Python, let the first step of Step Function call one Lambda function per query.
2. Parallelize query execution of Lambda Functions.
3. Call your Step Function from your pipeline, don't wait for the execution to finish.
4. Use [Amazon SNS](https://aws.amazon.com/sns/) to send an email to notify when Step Function has finished.

You can see your individual execution results in CloudWatch – useful for debugging and statistics.

This will work if each SQL query runs under 15 minutes. If not, you can consider running the script in container environment, EC2 Spot instance, or AWS Batch.

Comment: Thanks so much for the detailed explanation. But the step function needs to be completed successfully before the 30 hours script kicks in, the challenge is what to do after the 30 hours which you mention, to trigger the 30 hours script and dont wait for execution to finish but use amazon sns to send email when that is finished but to know if error occur might be the challenge

Comment: Can you breakdown that 30h script so that each execution unit runs under 15 minutes? Do you have sql queries in it? If yes, can you execute those queries separately, one query per Lambda execution?

Comment: I would need to ask the developer on that one how is possible.

Comment: Thank you. We have analysed it and so true we would use a way to break down those queries and use lambda for each stage of the queries for future improvement